# Setter doesn't save a variable in a SpringBoot Project as it should

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to validate the maximum number of teams a user can submit to my web application. In my `SubmitService` i have 2 methods that operate on my `int counting` variable

```
public void increment (@ModelAttribute Submit submit) {
        submit.setCounting(submit.getCounting() +1);
     }

    public void decrement (@ModelAttribute Submit submit) {
        submit.setCounting(submit.getCounting()-1);
    }
```

My `Submit` model where I validated Max counting - 4.

```
@Entity
public class Submit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Please enter your team name")
    private String name;
    private String rank;
    private String email;
    private String leader;

    private Integer score = 0;
    private Integer wins = 0;
    private Integer loses = 0;
    private Integer draws = 0;

    @Max(4)
    private int counting = 0;

    public Submit() {
    }
```

So if user does a Post = `counting+1`

```
@PostMapping("/submit")
    public String submitForm (@Valid @ModelAttribute("submit") Submit submit, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

        if (submit.getCounting()>=4) {
            return "submit_max";
        }

        else if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            List<String> rank = Arrays.asList("I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "X" );
            model.addAttribute("rank", rank);
            return "submit_form";
        } else {
            submitService.increment(submit);
            submitRepo.save(submit);
            System.out.println(submit.getCounting());
            return "submit_ok";
        }
    }
```

It adds correctly, in DEBUG mode first submitted team is increased from 0 to 1, but at second Post, counting is again increased from 0 to 1, not from 1 to 2 as it should be... What I don't understand there?

Comment: It depends on what is the initial value of `counting` in `submit` which is received in request body in controller.

Comment: In `Submit.class` I set `private int counting = 0;`. So I think controller gets a value =0, then goes to service where it's increased to 1, It looks like it in debug mode, but the second post is again value =0 and increased to 1 by service. It looks like at second POST method controller gets value =0 from `private int counting = 0;` ? or something? I Don't understand why at second post it isn't increased

Comment: `private int counting = 0;` will only work in case value is not set when object is received in controller. Also you need to preserve and send the value of `counting` back to controller during second request.

Comment: Thank you for comments. I guess I get the idea, but don't know how to implement it. How can i send back the value?